# autocompletion of python code in vim

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete

I need a editor in Linux like vim which would auto complete the python code for me.
Could someone please help me out with information and steps to be followed for configuring the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want an editor similar to Vim or just one with code completion?

Comment: Try Emacs, it has a sharp learning curve but is text based and programmable you'll love it with the span of time. There is Sublime and Eclipse too

Comment: @BleedingFingers, I'm an Emacs user myself. It's awesome, and I love to see other people using it. But it doesn't answer this question. Python auto-complete is available in Emacs and in Vim (which is also awesome).

Comment: @Chris It wasn't meant to be answer. It was an FYI kinda comment. Plus the question's off-topic here.

Comment: The FAQ does allow for questions regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers". Configuring code completion in a text editor probably qualifies under that heading.

Comment: @chepner "what have thou tried?" isn't there in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using Vim itself ?
The plugins [Pydiction](https://github.com/rkulla/pydiction) or [Jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) for Python and C++.